# Cakephp: add minutes to datetime object

Tags: cakephp, datetime, cakephp-2.2

I am new to cakephp and i wish to do the following:
I have a dateTime object and i want to add and subtract 30 minutes to it.
Following is my code in controller :

```
$time = $this->request->data['Rideoffer']['DepartureTime'];
                    $date = new DateTime($time['hour'] . ':' . $time['min'] . ' ' . $time['meridian']); 

                        $currentDate = strtotime($date['date']); // this line gives error
                        $futureDate = $currentDate+(60*30);
                        $formatDate = date("Y-m-d H:i", $futureDate);
```

when i debug $date i get the following result:

```
 object(DateTime) {
 date => '2013-03-08 05:54:00'
 timezone_type => (int) 3
 timezone => 'UTC'
}
```

i wish to extract `date` from this object. How do i do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it:

```
 $currentDate = strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

but i still dont get it that why cant i use $date['date'], i mean $date like an array.

Comment: Concerning the last paragraph - you can still ask anew or search ;-)